# TinyMCE force content into into an ordered list (ol)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

Is there a way to force the editor to begin with an `ol` so when the user clicks `enter`, it will automatically go to a new `li`. The user should also not be able to exit the `ol`, so when they click `enter` on an empty line, it should stay in the `ol`.

I have tried `forced_root_block : 'li'` and `forced_root_block : 'ol'` but they don't seem to do anything.

I have also looked through TinyMCE's documentation but couldn't find any way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "link, paste",
    toolbar: 'numlist',
    valid_elements : "-ol,-li",
    menubar: false,
    paste_as_text: true,
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on("init", function() {
            editor.execCommand('InsertOrderedList');
        });
        // This forces all 'enter' and 'backspace' keys to create an 'ol li' element
        editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 8){
                if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'li'){
                    editor.execCommand('InsertOrderedList');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The paste as text plugin is so when the user pastes a large number of text, it won't break the `li`